# -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I was installing a boilerplate in my Mac, then it says `your node version is outdated` and `we can't find gulp, try npm install gulp`,

I put in my console

`npm install -g npm; npm install gulp`

and after that, it doesn't matter what I do with `npm . . .` in the terminal, I always get this `-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

here my last logs

```
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$ npm start
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$ npm cache clean
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$ sudo npm install npm -g
Password:
sudo: npm: command not found
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$ npm -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$ node -v
v4.1.0
CRSJOPGP0223:nodeboilerplate bermarce$
```

I have that version of node, `v4.1.0`, but anything with npm works.

Do you guys have an idea ?

**EDIT**

> -bash: nvm: command not found

**UPDATE**

I just uninstall everything regarding `node` and `nvm` in my Mac, then install node and nvm again and it works, I do `nvm` and `node` and `npm` and returns some instructions so this means it is installed.

But if I open a new tab in the terminal and type the same, I got no responde

`-bash: nvm: command not found` <--that again

so then I installed again everything in the new tab of the terminal and it works again. Is like if its not installed globally or something.

Comment: Are you using `nvm`? https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @juandemarco see my edit

Comment: Try reinstalling `nvm` (the instructions are on the repo page) and then `nvm install v4 && nvm use v4`

Comment: @juandemarco see my update

Answer (score 4):

1. make the directory

   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

2.Create a symbolic link from the installed location to the location it is looking for

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: I was having problem running npm commands from a bash script. This solution is what ultimately worked. In case anyone is wondering how to find installed location, run `which npm`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `nvm` is not in your path. Open up your `~/.bashrc` file (or `~/.zshrc` if you're using `zsh`) and add this at the end:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Save, exit and open another terminal tab and everything should be ok!

Comment: If that file is not there, just create with "sudo nano ~/.bashrc". You answer did the trick on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit old, but as other people might still stumple upon it...
The [installation process of nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) should have added these lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

There's no need to add `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fix some permission errors and clearly did the wrong thing, resulting in whenever i used npm it would give me:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

I just went to node.js website and selected the installer,
ran that.
Once completed it setup all the files required.

This sorted my npm installation issues out for me.

*Edit*

Not quite i still needed to setup permissions to install in node, but it does setup the required directories.

I had a look at this video to see how to update my permissions cause my user didn't have access to my node_modules file

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxvybxYFq2o

hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

- sudo apt-get install nodejs
- sudo npm -v

You can see the installed npm version